# How to use props in a function in class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component

I have a problem. I used React Router to examine the URL path.

```
<Route path="/:brand" component={Container} />
```

I used it in the Container component

```
import React from 'react';
import CarPage from '../components/CarPage';
import '../styles/Container.css';

const Container = ({ match }) => {
    return (
       <CarPage brand={match.params.brand} />
   );
}

export default Container;
```

And in the component I want to use it in the "findMyIndex" function which is to check its index in the "carList" array

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CarPage extends Component {
    state = {
        index: 0,
    }
    carList = ["Ford", "Fiat", "Ferrari"];

    findMyIndex = (props.brand) => {
        console.log(props.brand);    
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <p>{this.props.brand}</p>
        );
    }
}

export default CarPage;
```

Then he has to enter the found index in this.state.index. The problem is that I have no idea how to properly use props in a function in a class component. I am a beginner and would like to know how to use "brand" correctly in "findMyIndex". Please help.

Comment: I haven't used classes in forever, but since arrow functions inherit context, doesn't `this.props.brand` work? (Without passing the value into the arrow function at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your props is accessible anywhere within the class. You can access it inside your `findMyIndex` method like this:

```
findMyIndex = () => {
    console.log(this.props.brand);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I have one more question, how can I call a function "findMyIndex" under a paragraph?

Comment: what does that function do ? and what does it return ?

Comment: This function in your answer, im trying sth like this but this not working: {this.findMyIndex()}

Comment: As of now your function doesn't do anything except printing the brand to the console .

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how to get it to show up on the console. Something like this doesn't work:   `render(){return(<p>{this.props.brand}</p>{this.findMyIndex()})}`

Comment: Solved I forgot about React Fragment <> </>